# Where do I get FFMPEG dll for php 5.6.25 for windows 8

Tags: wamp, php-extension, php-5.6, ffmpeg-php

Hi I have installed wamp with php 5.6.25. I need to enable ffmpeg. I have done the followings:

Option one:
I have followed what has provided in this link http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows, but it didn't work

Option two:

- Downloaded dll from http://myownhomeserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/ffmpeg6-php54-win64-vc9-all.zip
- Copied dll file in F:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext
- Added line extension=php_ffmpeg.dll on php.ini fine and restarted the wamp

But it didn't work in either way. When I check the extensions, it says no extension for ffmpeg.

Could anyone suggest what I am missing  here. It would be great help.

Thanks in advance